# how to create project for native c++ executable in visual studio 2012

Tags: visual-c++, exe, visual-studio-2012

how to create project for native c++ executable in visual studio 2012. In previous version New Project -> Visual C++ -> Win32 Project. I installed msvc 2012 RC and can't find anything like that.

Comment: Rule #1: Every new version (at least) doubles the number of key-strokes/mouse clicks to do anything simple.

Comment: It is called VS11. And then user20312 answers your question. And then I agree with Jerry. But for one thing you can find it in Recent once you have done one project already lik that.

Comment: @Xebo - The beta was called VS11, the release candidate is called [VS2012](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/11/en-us). Just to add to this confusion?

Comment: You win. Microsoft marketing is screwing with us. That is at the link of http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/11/en-us (11 there) is Visual Studio 2012. What a consistency.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you see when you open the new project dialog depends on what setting you chose when you loaded VS for the first time. If you chose something other than C++ or General Development settings, C++ will be hidden by default. Then you may have to expand "Other Languages" to see it.

If you chose C++ or General Development settings, however, you should see Visual C++ as on option in the new project dialog. There will be Visual C++ -> Win32 Console Application.

Answer (score 0):

File -> New Project -> Installed -> Templates -> Other Languages -> Visual C++ -> Win32 Project )))

Comment: What if "Visual C++" is not listed there?