# Visual Studio 2012 - Can't create win32 projects

Tags: visual-studio-2012, wizard

I'm using Visual Studio 2012, update 1 on a Windows 8 machine. When I try to start a new win32 project using the application wizard something weird appens:

- the windows that welcomes to the wizard has three empty bullets under "these are the current project settings". Both the cancel and the finish button do not work.

The folder for the application is created but no files inside.

please help!!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11270148/1064610

Comment: It sounds like you have some VS2012 templates missing or corrupted. Have you tried re-installing VS2012?

Comment: I do not wish to uninstall VS2012, but if no other options left, I'll try. 
I'm currently trying with the repair option, then I'll uninstall it.

Comment: Unistalled, CCleaned and reinstalled... the problem is exactly there... 

Bythe way I notice that some of the preferences of the previous install are still there.

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem forcing a "clean" install of VS2012. ('clean' means that also the shared packages were uninstalled). Presuming that the installer I used to install VS2012 was on d:

```
D:\vs_premium.exe /uninstall /force
```

Once reinstalled, the problem was gone.

Answer (score 0):

I am running Visual Studio Express 2012 for WP on Macbook via Parallels.

I did the update of VS today and could not load my project (HTML App, #C) nor create new projects afterwards.
**The solution was to go to Windows program uninstall for Visual Studio Express 2012, BUT choose option "Repair"**. It took about the same time as the update but I was able to create new projects afterwards (my existing own app project from November 2012 also works).

Before I "repaired" the installation, I have removed manually from VS->Tools->Extensions and Updates a few packages added "Nu Get Package Manager and Packager". I am not sure if the latter is really needed.

Additional info: My VS 2012 Express for Windows8 installation worked and works w/o issues.