# No Option for making C++ Win32 Application in VS 2012

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, console-application

I am using VS 2012 on Windows 8 64 bit, I downloaded it for making simple C++ Win23 console applications, but when I select File > New Project... there is no such option.

Is it that Win32 Console Apps cannot be made in VS 2012?
I only want to make C++ console applications

My actual problem is that I don't have the Win32 option in File > New Project > Visual C++.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15360846/visual-studio-2012-cant-create-win32-projects

Comment: What version of vs do you have? If it's the express version do you have "visual c++ 2012 for windows desktop"? If it's the full version not express then never mind...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Win32 Console Apps can be made with VS 2012 on Win8 x64.  The "File -> New Project" wizard has a list of templates on the left side for various project types.  Make sure you have the appropriate set selected.  You'll find "Win32 Console Application" on the top if you select "Templates -> Visual C++" or "Templates -> Visual C++ -> Win32".  If your templates are not there, there may have been an installation problem.

**EDIT** also, if you're targeting older OS versions, change your "Properties -> General -> Platform Toolset" to "v110_xp".

Comment: My problem is that I don' have the Win32 option.