# Only empty project template appears in Visual Studio when creating new project

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

On my desktop installation, when I open a new project I don't see any templates (e.g. console application) but the empty solution

here 
[image]

How can I open console application?
(I dont have an option to install it)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can [reinstall the default templates without reinstalling Visual Studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms247116%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), to do this you need to open the VS location in command prompt, followed by the `/installvstemplates` command

*Note: You need to run the command as an administrator*

Express Version:

```
> cd C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\
> WDExpress.exe /installvstemplates
```

Other versions:

```
> cd C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\
> devenv.exe /installvstemplates
```

If that doesn't work, you will need to reinstall Visual Studio. You might want to check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15360846/1218281) question, essentially you may have to uninstall and then reinstall Visual Studio, or "repair" it through the installer.

Most likely anyone could give you the files necessary but I don't believe Microsoft wants them distributed unofficially.